# Thread - contention vs race

Tags: parallel-computing, threads, multi-tasking, critical-section

The terms `contention` and `race` are used interchangeably when it comes to thread's state(at critical section). Are they same?

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without wasting anybody's time. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61919294/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/126013/755, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587920/9812.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two distinct phenomena.   Contention refers to the fact that when thread $A$ has accessed a resource $B$ needs to wait until $A$ frees it.

Race refers to the fact when both threads $A$ and $B$ want to secure access to a resource.  The fastest will secure it and thus lead to contention.

Comment: +1, although it's worth mentioning that a race does not necessarily lead to *observable* contention. This depends on how the processes are scheduled. For example if we use a single processor we might be able to guarantee that neither thread is ever blocked by the other, e.g. if A and B race to acquire a resource but both always manage to free it within a single scheduling quantum. Of course there could be contention elsewhere (e.g. in the caching protocol) but at least A and B will never need to wait for the other to free the resource.